# Taylor's formula with Lagrange remainder: what does mean "between"

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have encountered a proof, which relies on the assumption that $\theta$ in Lagrange remainder is strictly within the interval $(a,b)$

$f(x) = f(a) + f'(\theta) (x-a)$

meaning that for this proof it is important that $\theta\neq a$ and $\theta\neq b$. I've decided to google this question and every article says that $\theta$ is *between* $a$ and $b$, but does not say what *beween* means. Does it mean in $\theta\in[a,b]$ or $\theta\in(a,b)$?

Comment: $\theta\in(\min(a,b),\max(a,b))$.

Comment: The Lagrange remainder theorem gives us a number $\theta \in (a,x)$. You can read about the Lagrange form of the remainder here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/taylors-theorem-with-lagrange-remainder/